# What is the level order of the official Alien Swarm campaigns?

Tags: alien-swarm

Whats the order of levels of the official campaigns of Alien Swarm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of the Jacob's Rest campaign, which as of August 2010 is the only official campaign that's been released, is as follows:

1. Landing Bay
2. Cargo Elevator
3. Deima Surface Bridge
4. Rydberg Reactor
5. SynTek Residential
6. Sewer Junction B5
7. Timor Station

You can still play the levels in any order. The only difference that playing them in order makes is that you will get more of a feel for the overarching story.